# In Python, can I bind a variable to a function/expression so that it automatically updates?

Tags: python

Let's say I've got a variable A that is the result of a function/expression F. F in it's turn has a number of other variables in it, let's say X,Y and Z.

Is it possible to bind A to F so that whenever X,Y or Z changes, A will be updated automatically?

What I want to avoid is that everytime X,Y and Z changes, I have to remember to update A explicitly in the code. I also don't want to call the function everytime I want to use the A.

Example (as per requested): I've got the following function:

```
def calcHits():
    return sum(hitDiceRolls,level*modList['con'])
```

and in my program (outside of the function), I've got a variable called hitPoints (yes, it's a roleplaying game program). Whenever the variables that's used in the function is changed, I want hitPoints to change as well.

Comment: You will need to give an example

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property can you use something like that?

Comment: I've been looking at that, and it would work. In that case I would write code that updates the relevant variables in the setter-part of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in Python to automatically rebind a name in global or local scope in response to other names being rebound.  However, it should be possible to make a class that can keep track of some values and have a member function that returns the value you called `A`.  And, as @Alok pointed out, you can use property descriptors to make a member name that implicitly calls a function to return its value, so you can hide the function and treat the name like a plain old name.

```
class Trk(object):
    """Track some values and compute a function if any change"""
    def __init__(self, name, fn, **objects_to_track):
        def _trk_fn(self):
            if any(self.__dict__[x] != self.original_objects[x] for x in self.original_objects):
                self.value = self.saved_fn(self.__dict___)
                # now that self.value is updated, also update self.original_objects
                for x in self.original_objects:
                    self.original_objects[x] = self.__dict__[x]
            return self.value

        self.original_objects = objects_to_track  # make reference copy
        self.__dict__.update(objects_to_track)
        self.name = name
        self.saved_fn = fn
        self.fn = self._trk_fn()
        self.value = self.fn()
```

I'm sorry but I am very tired right now, and I canot finish this example.  I didn't test it either.  But this shows one way to track values, and if they are different, do something different.  You use it like this:

```
# want to track x, y, z
trk = Trk(x, y, z)
trk.fn() # returns up-to-date value

trk.x = new_value
trk.fn() #detects that trk.x changed and computes new trk.value
```

If the above works, you can use the property descriptor stuff to bind a name such that an attempt to read a value from the name will call `self.fn()`

EDIT: Oh, it's important that when `self.value` is updated, `self.original_objects` should be updated.  I've added code to do that.

And now I'm going to sleep!

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to do this in Python would be to use a `class`:

```
class ExpressionBinder:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.z = 0

    @property
    def result(self):
        return self.f(self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

You can use it like this:

```
def f(x, y, z):
    return x**3 + y**2 + z

b = ExpressionBinder(f)
b.x = 1
b.y = 2
b.z = 3
print(b.result)
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the elegance of sending in the actual function as well (which makes it very dynamic). It's still pulling the result every time I whant to use the resulting value, but I'm guessing that's the only solution currently

Comment: If the function is expensive to run, you could cache the result and only recalculate the result if the input values have changed since the last time you ran it.

Comment: True, I have to check that out. Thanks!